# Which classifier to be used in a recommendation problem?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, recommender-system

I am supposed to deal with a recommendation problem in which the input vectors of 1 million bits represents the interest of 1 million people in a special product and the output would be the a binary value shows a special new customer will like the product or not. The classifier should be "UPDATED" frequently in order to adapt new data.

considering Naive Bayes, Logistic regression, Gaussian Naive Bayes and Neural Networks, which one is better for this type of problem?

P.S: If the choice is neural network, then how can I encode the 1 million bits? Does it mean that I have to have 1 million input neurons in my input layer??? Can we update a neural network classifier easily?

Comment: Recommendations are usually done using matrix factorization methods, rather than those you listed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean usually SVD or NMF is used instead of any classifier?

Comment: SVD is an option, too. Key thing to notice is that your data matrix is incomplete, and to do recommendations, you need to impute missing values. Also, because of missing values, you can't apply usual decomposition algorithms, you need something different.